# How to shut down when only at the encryption password page?

Tags: 14.04, encryption, shutdown

Possibly a silly question. I have my hard drive encrypted so on turning on my laptop I have to enter my hard drive password. There is nothing else on this screen. If I wish to shut down my computer at this point what is the safest way of doing it?

I would hope there is a way of doing it without having to log in and then having to shut down.

Running 14.04 on my machine. It has 2 hard drives; one for Ubuntu and the other for `/home`. There is only full disk encryption on the OS Hard Drive.

Comment: If you're using full-disk encryption, then you can be sure nothing is being written (since you haven't decrypted the drive). As such a hardware power-off (eg hold the power button) should be entirely safe. If you are only encrypting (for example) /home (doesn't sound like it), it's a bit trickier

Comment: @Darael Have 2 hard drives. Will edit question to update.

Comment: If the FDE is on the OS drive, as you say, you can still be sure nothing is being written, because the OS can't mount the /home drive (or even know that it would *need* to mount it) until said OS is decrypted!

Comment: If the FDE is on /home (just for reference), it's a mite trickier. I'd be inclined to use the Magic SysRq sequence REISUO in that case, with multi-second pauses between each. It's almost certainly not the best option for that situation, though - just the first thing to spring to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using full-disk encryption on the OS drive, and you have not yet entered the password to decrypt that disk, you may be sure that nothing is being written there. You can also know that nothing is being written to the disk containing `/home`, as without decrypting the OS drive the system can't access `/etc/fstab` and thereby discover that it *needs* to mount `/home`, let alone actually mount it.

As such, it should be entirely safe to power off the machine in any reasonable way. While pulling the plug seems unnecessary, an ACPI power-off (by holding the power button) should be fine.

As a side note, if the system were booted to such a point that disk writes *were* a possibility, but login (or display-manager shutdown) *wasn't*, my first instinct (though probably not the best answer) would be a Magic SysRq sequence, probably REISUO, with appropriate multi-second pauses between commands.

Answer (score 2):

LVM Encrypted Ubuntu 18.04 could be shut down from the boot-time decrypt page by escaping to grub (example 2.04) command line then commanding to halt.

```
[Ctrl] + [Alt] + [Delete]      (Escape to grub menu)
[Esc]                          (Escape to grub command line)
grub> halt     + [Enter]       ("The command halts the computer")
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if You have some FULL drive/disk encryption, and need to "unlock" to boot further than the bootloader (either BIOS/UEFI, or a GNU/Linux bootloader (like GRUB))...?

If above is the case, I agree with earlier posters - it's safe to do a hard shutdown by pressing down the power button for the seconds needed (usually 3-6 s. depending on model).

Elaborations below...

Even IF any other file system is mounted (or  encryption backing FS/partition), the system is basically running in a pre-boot environment with extremely little writing going on (if any)...

Hardly *any* fairly modern file system would fail patching up the few *bytes* that could disappear due to a shutdown.

(And if You're using spinning disks (mechanical hard drives) and worry about read/write-heads falling to disk surfaces and scratching them because of power down, that won't happen, they "auto park" safely.)